# phpMyAdmin on IIS port 81 delivers stylesheet as HTML

Tags: php, iis, phpmyadmin, port

I am attempting to run phpMyAdmin on IIS on port 81 (there is a public site running on port 80 and I am restricting access to phpMyAdmin to localhost only).

It works fine but the style sheet is not being loaded, returning this error:

> The stylesheet
>   http://127.0.0.1:81/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=5944058898ltr was not
>   loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Inspection of the source code shows that url is returning an HTML page instead of the style sheet.

When running phpMyAdmin in a subdirectory of the main site on port 80 it works fine, and the equivalent url returns css as expected.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What happens if you make it a subdirectory on the port 81 site and configure the port 81 side the same way as the port 80 side?

Comment: I tried moving it to a subdirectory, got the same result. I've also checked permissions on the directory.

Comment: I tried this again and got it working. If I install it to a subdirectory pma in the web root directory, and browse to http://127.0.0.1:81/pma/index.php it loads as expected. It seems to work OK, although when I login it takes me back to http://127.0.0.1:81 and I have to type the subdirectory in again.